# Convergence in weak topology implies pointwise convergence for a subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Prove that if a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset L^p$, $1<p<\infty$ converges in the weak topology to an element $x \in L^p$, then there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of it that converges almost everywhere to $x$. From Mazur's lemma, we can find convex combinations that converge strongly to $x$, but I couldnt finish the problem from there. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Strong convergence implies convergence almost everywhere (at least for a subsequence). Convex combinations must then converge almost everywhere to...?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos thanks for your comment. The problem is that the number of elements in the convex combination increases. I cant see how to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. The sequence
$$
x_n := sign(\sin(n \pi t)
$$
converges weakly in $L^p(0,1)$ to $x=0$. But $x_n\ne0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Great answer. Could you please elaborate on the weak convergence? I wasnt able to follow that step. Thank you!

Comment: see eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536412/how-to-show-weak-convergence-of-mathrmsign-sinnx-as-n-to-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1