A property of solution operator of a elliptic PDE involving positive part of a function
For a given $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, there is a unique $S(u) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla S(u) \nabla \varphi + S(u) \varphi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u \varphi, \quad \forall \varphi \in H^1_{\mathbb{R}^N}.
$$
I want to prove that, for $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, the following inequality holds
$$
(1) \,\,\,\,\, \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u^{+} S(u^+) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u S(u).
$$
What I know and can be used: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u S(u) \geq 0$ for any $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u S(v) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} v S(u)$ for any $u,v \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
I know how to prove $(1)$ assuming two situations, which I don't know it if true or not. The first one is assuming $u(x)S(u^+)(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in \{x \in \mathbb{R}^N : u(x) < 0\}$. The second one is assuming $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u^-S(u^+) = 0$. Some of this two conditions are  true in fact?

I think this inequality cannot be true. Here is a counterexample for $N=1$:
Define $u_n(x) := \sin(2n\pi x) \chi_{[0,1]}$. Then $u_n \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^2(0,1)$ and in $L^2(\mathbb R)$. The sequence $(S(u_n))$ is bounded in $H^1(\mathbb R)$ and $H^1(0,1)$, and there is a subsequence converging strongly in $L^2(0,1)$. This implies $\int_{\mathbb R} u_n S(u_n) =\int_0^1 u_nS(u_n)\to 0$.
Now $u_n^+ \rightharpoonup v:=\chi_{[0,1]}c$, where $c = \int_0^1 (\sin(2\pi x))^+ dx>0$. This implies $S(v) \ne0$, and
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} S(v)v = \|S(v)\|_{H^1(\mathbb R)}^2 >0.
$$
Similarly to the arguments in the first paragraph, we get $\int_{\mathbb R} u_n^+ S(u_n^+) \to \int_{\mathbb R} v S(v) >0$.
So the right-hand side of the desired inequality tends to zero, while the left-hand side tends to some positive number. And the inequality cannot be true.
(The same arguments show that the inequality cannot be true if we replace $\mathbb R^N$ by any domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$.)

Do you know how to prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u^- S(u^+) = 0 ?$ This would help me because $\int_{\mathbb{R}N} u S(u) = \int_{\mathbb{R}N} u^+ S(u^+)  + \int_{\mathbb{R}N} u^- S(u^-) - 2 \int_{\mathbb{R}N} u^- S(u^+)$.

If your answer is true, then is it impossible to have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u^- S(u^+) = 0$, right?

Yes, this integral cannot be zero then.

Thank you for the answer. I didn't understand why $\int_0^1 u_nS(u_n)\to 0$. Could you, please, clarify it ? I have no ideia, because the norm of $u_n$ in $L^2$ is constant for all $n$.

For weak convergence of $u_n$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536412/how-to-show-weak-convergence-of-mathrmsign-sinnx-as-n-to-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1
